# AWS ECS EC2: TaskCanceledException when calling AWS API (connection timed out)

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-secrets-manager

I have set up an AWS ECS cluster with EC2-type container instances. In task definition, there is "SECRETS" environment variable specified with the value corresponding to a particular secret name. Task definition uses awsvpc network mode.

In order to access secrets value from code (.net) following code (from [aws snippet](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/code-samples/latest/catalog/code-catalog-dotnet-example_code-SecretsManager-GetSecretValue.html))  is used:

```
IAmazonSecretsManager client = new AmazonSecretsManagerClient(region);
GetSecretValueRequest request = new GetSecretValueRequest
{
  SecretId = secretName,
  VersionStage = "AWSCURRENT" // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified.
};
GetSecretValueResponse response = Task.Run(async () => await client.GetSecretValueAsync(request)).Result;
```

This works perfectly with **Fargate** instance type. When switching to **EC2** container instance  GetSecretValueAsync() fails with AggregateException : ***TaskCanceledException***.

I've tried to [get IAM role credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html) from the inside of the container with success:

```
curl 169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

I've also tried specifying retrieved credentials directly with no luck:

```
AmazonSecretsManagerClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, region)
```

In addition, I've tried baking aws cli inside the container, and from the inside I've tried `aws secretsmanager` , `aws iam get-user` and `aws sts get-caller-identity` - still hangs without response. 
I've granted full admin access to task execution role - still no success. I'm able to retrieve secrets from EC2 container instance, but not from the mounted container.

Comment: A long shot, but are you using the latest version of the ECS AMI?

Comment: @mcheshier I've tried new LC with updated AMI with no luck. In addition, I've tried baking aws cli inside the container, and from the inside aws secretsmanager, aws iam get-user or even aws sts get-caller-identity hangs without response. Looks like there is some IAM permissions, I've missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to AWS support, the solution was found.
The key issue of my configuration was a [combination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-networking.html) of **awsvpc** networking mode and **EC2 launch type** for containers:

> The awsvpc network mode does not provide task ENIs with public IP
>   addresses for tasks that use the EC2 launch type. To access the
>   internet, tasks that use the EC2 launch type must be launched in a
>   private subnet that is configured to use a NAT gateway

Instead, I've moved to bridge networking with [dynamic port mapping](https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/) (achieved by using Application Load Balancer). I've also used host networking mode for some specific tasks - this worked as well.